# Recycler View with three large images scrolling slow, how can I fix this?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My recycler view works well, it loads the three images, but the images are of a high quality (500kb roughly each), and it causes the scrolling to lag. 
So how can i make my adapter for the recycler view load the images to the ImageView efficiently so that my app does not skip frames and cause the scrolling to lag ?

Here is what my adapter looks look,

```
package com.erbowl.erbowlbeta;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by nucogroup on 10/22/2015.
 */
public class dashboardItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<dashboardItemsAdapter.dashboardItemsViewHolder>{

    DashboardItem[] mDashboardItems;
    public dashboardItemsAdapter(DashboardItem[] dashboardItems){
        mDashboardItems = dashboardItems;
    }

    @Override
    public dashboardItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.dashboard_list_item, viewGroup, false);

        dashboardItemsViewHolder viewHolder = new dashboardItemsViewHolder(view);

       return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(dashboardItemsViewHolder dashboardItemsViewHolder, int i) {
                dashboardItemsViewHolder.bindItem(mDashboardItems[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDashboardItems.length;
    }

    public class dashboardItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView mTexttext;

        public dashboardItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
          itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
          mTexttext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strainTT);
        }

        public void bindItem(DashboardItem dashboardItem){

            itemImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            itemImage.setImageResource(dashboardItem.getmMainImage());
            mTexttext.setText(dashboardItem.getmTitle());
        }
    }


}
```

[Here's what the ui interface of the three images looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4goP6.png)

Comment: "but the images are of a high quality (500kb roughly each)" -- is "500kb" referring to the size on disk?

Comment: @CommonsWare  the three images being loaded as items in the recycler view are each approximately each 500-700kb each. which are on disk, if on disk means having these images in my drawable folder

Comment: did you read through this? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Um, those images are huge. Uncompressed, in memory, those will take up several MB apiece. You may not have enough heap space for those on some devices, causing an `OutOfMemoryError`, beyond any performance problems that you are seeing now. They will also have a resolution that is beyond what is necessary for rendering what you want based upon your attached screenshot. In general, use Traceview to determine where your problem lies. In this case, I recommend using lower-resolution images.

Comment: thank you! I just lowered them in photoshop to 60kb each. Now I understand i can read through the documentation which I have thoroughly and came across AsyncTask and decodeSampledBitmapFromResource, can you provide me with an example for a beginner like me to be able to walk through ?